# jquery ui override the css class, how to avoid it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am new in jquery, i am using rails 3.2.19 and jquery-ui-rails 5.0.0.
I am create button using css class="button", when ajax call it override css property
like this class="button_new ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all  how to avoid this.

```
.button_new {  
    background: #3b5998;  
    padding: 4px 8px;  
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;  
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;  
    border-radius: 8px;  
    color: #ffffff;  
    font-size: 11px;  
    font-family: Georgia, Serif;  
    text-decoration: none;  
    vertical-align: middle;   
}

.button_new:hover {  
    border-top-color: #edf0f5;  
    background: #edf0f5;  
    color: #ff0000;  
}

.button_new:active {  
    border-top-color: #dfe7eb;  
    background: #dfe7eb;  
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code? How these classes are applied on your button?

Comment: hi i added my css code above

Comment: Your class is applied dynamically so why you think css is causing the issue? It would be some js code. You can remove it by js as someone has already answered it

Answer (score 1):

First, I would add an ID to the button so we don't override some instances where you want jQuery UI to set its own classes.

```
<button id="my-button" class="button">My Button</button>
```

Then you can load your own jQuery script after jQuery UI is executed and use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // remove jQuery UI classes
  $('#my-button').removeClass('button_new ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all');
  // add button class back
  $('#my-button').addClass('button');
});
```

This will replace the auto-generated classes with your classes, while not conflicting with other instances where you need jQuery UI to exhibit this behavior.